# How to insert a URL link into a PHP define tag

Tags: php, url, text, hyperlink

I am an absolute newby to php so please be gentle.

I have the following line...

```
define('TEXT_INFORMATION', '<b>Note:</b> You can check their rate calculator here, and you are welcome to contact us.');
```

I want to place a html link to the post office website where it says 'here' and a link to my contact page where it says 'contact us'. How to do pls?

Comment: Just like you inserted bold text.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for

```
define('TEXT_INFORMATION', '<b>Note:</b> You can check their rate calculator here, and you are welcome to <a href="your link">here</a>.');
```

replace your link to contact us page in the href tag where i have put "your link"

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the words in HTML anchor tags, something like this:

```
define('TEXT_INFORMATION', '... <a href="YOUR URL">here</a> ...'
```